NN training by optimizing hidden layer content with information bottleneck "inf_T I(X;T) - beta I(T;Y)"?
There was a lot of hype about Naftali Tishby's information bottleneck method a few years ago, but it is nearly silent now, especially that sadly the author has died in 2021.
In theory it allows to directly optimize the content of hidden/intermediate layer T - that it should not only maximize mutual information about the output I(T;Y), but simultaneously also minimize information about the input I(X;T) - remove noise, (lossy) compress/extract the most valuable information.
In Tishby's talks like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utvIaZ6wYuw he uses it for evaluation, but it seems tempting to try to directly use it for training - optimize content of intermediate layers. Personally I see it quite promising, currently working on new ANNs which can be cheaply trained this way ( https://arxiv.org/abs/2405.05097 ), so wanted to ask if it makes sense.
Was this e.g. "inf_T I(X;T) - beta I(T;Y)" directly used for NN training? Should it be?
Maybe some more sophisticated minimization-maximization would be better?

Update: Turned out there is direct training with information bottleneck - HSIC in 1 and 2, using similar central formula Tr(Kx Ky) as I have found, but on local basis (KDE, width dependent) while I use global (polynomial on variables normalized to U[0,1]). Their diagram claiming it is more biologically plausible training:

